# Sorting arrays with if else statements

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, ascii

So, I'm working on a project in java in which I have to intake a string and count the frequencies of characters in the string. Then, I have to sort the characters into four categories: textual, white space, numerical, and symbols. I'm looking for a way to do that. For counting the frequency in the string, this is what I have so far:

```
    char[] charArray = userSort.toCharArray();
        char tempChar;
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
                if (charArray[i] < charArray[j]) {
                    tempChar = charArray[i];
                    charArray[i] = charArray[j];
                    charArray[j] = tempChar;]
```

I also have the concept for how I would like to sort and print these statements using if-else statements.

```
 int whiteSpace = 0;
            int textual = 0;
            int numerical = 0;
            int symbols = 0;

        if() {
            whiteSpace++;
        }

        else if (){
            textual++;
            }

        else if (){
            numerical++;
        }
        else {
            symbols++;
        }
            System.out.println("Textual Character count: " + textual);
            System.out.println("Numerical Character count: " + numerical);
            System.out.println("Whitespace Character count: " + whiteSpace);
            System.out.println("Symbol character count: " + symbols);
```

I'm just not sure of what I use for the if else statements to keep it in the particular categories. I'm also unsure of how to combine both codes together. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Also, I can't use **built-in** java sorting functions or anything like that.

Comment: Your sorting algorithm (something like a Bubble sort) is not correct. Why do you need to sort the data since you need to count them?

Comment: I am not sure if this will help at all but you can store them in different arrays and sort each array separately.

Comment: hint for categories assuming ascii input (c==' ')('a'<=c&&c<='z'||'A'<=c&&c<='Z')('0'<=c&&c<='9')

Comment: @davidbuzatto It is Bubble sort! There are three parts of my code: one sorts in alphabetical order, one sorts by frequencies, and for the last, I have to put everything in categories. I was just going to continue using the same method to count. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: Take a look in my updated answer. You bubble sort has a little problem. My second code snnippet will solve your problem.

Comment: just answering the frequency part https://ideone.com/LdhRWn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a starting point for you, using a Map to store the countings:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestCount {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String myString = "abc abc abc abc aaabbbccc 0000 *&% a";
        int whiteSpace = 0;
        int textual = 0;
        int numerical = 0;
        int symbols = 0;

        char[] data = myString.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort( data );

        Map<Character, Integer> countMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for ( char c : data ) {
            if ( countMap.containsKey( c ) ) {
                countMap.put( c, countMap.get( c ) + 1 );
            } else {
                countMap.put( c, 1 );
            }
        }

        for ( Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : countMap.entrySet() ) {

            char key = e.getKey();
            System.out.printf( "%c -> %d occurences\n", e.getKey(), e.getValue() );

            if ( ( key >= 'a' && key <= 'z' ) || ( key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z' ) ) {
                textual += e.getValue();
            } else if ( key >= '0' && key <= '9' ) {
                numerical += e.getValue();
            } else if ( key == ' ' ) {
                whiteSpace += e.getValue();
            } else {
                symbols += e.getValue();
            }

        }

        System.out.printf( "%d are textual characters\n", textual );
        System.out.printf( "%d are numerical characters\n", numerical );
        System.out.printf( "%d are whitespace characters\n", whiteSpace );
        System.out.printf( "%d are symbol characters\n", symbols );

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a simple and dirty solution without using build in capabilities like sorting and map. It maps the char code (integer that represents the char) to an array position. Since the chars are ordered, the last char of the data array is the char with the bigger code and will be the last valid array position.

```
public class TestCount {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String myString = "abc abc abc abc aaabbbccc 0000 *&% a";
        int whiteSpace = 0;
        int textual = 0;
        int numerical = 0;
        int symbols = 0;

        char[] data = myString.toCharArray();
        mySort( data );

        // a counting array. it will waste a lot of space, but it will work
        int[] countArray = new int[ (int) data[data.length-1] + 1 ];

        for ( char c : data ) {
            countArray[ (int) c ]++;
        }

        char lastChar = '\0';
        for ( char c : data ) {

            if ( c != lastChar ) {
                System.out.printf( "%c -> %d occurences\n", c, countArray[ (int) c ] );
            }

            if ( ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) || ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) ) {
                textual++;
            } else if ( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ) {
                numerical++;
            } else if ( c == ' ' ) {
                whiteSpace++;
            } else {
                symbols++;
            }

            lastChar = c;

        }

        System.out.printf( "%d are textual characters\n", textual );
        System.out.printf( "%d are numerical characters\n", numerical );
        System.out.printf( "%d are whitespace characters\n", whiteSpace );
        System.out.printf( "%d are symbol characters\n", symbols );

    }

    public static void mySort( char[] array ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++ ) {
                if ( array[j] > array[j+1] ) {
                    char t = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:** An slightly more space efficient approach:

```
public class TestCount {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String myString = "abc abc abc abc aaabbbccc 0000 *&% a";
        int whiteSpace = 0;
        int textual = 0;
        int numerical = 0;
        int symbols = 0;

        char[] data = myString.toCharArray();
        mySort( data );

        // a counting array. it will waste a lot of space, but it will work
        int[] countArray = new int[ (int) data[data.length-1] + 1 - (int) data[0]  ];

        for ( char c : data ) {
            countArray[ map(data[0], c) ]++;
        }

        char lastChar = '\0';
        for ( char c : data ) {

            if ( c != lastChar ) {
                System.out.printf( "%c -> %d occurence(s)\n", c, countArray[ map(data[0], c)  ] );
            }

            if ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'z' ) {
                textual++;
            } else if ( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ) {
                numerical++;
            } else if ( c == ' ' ) {
                whiteSpace++;
            } else {
                symbols++;
            }

            lastChar = c;

        }

        System.out.printf( "%d are textual characters\n", textual );
        System.out.printf( "%d are numerical characters\n", numerical );
        System.out.printf( "%d are whitespace characters\n", whiteSpace );
        System.out.printf( "%d are symbol characters\n", symbols );

    }

    public static int map( char leftBoundary, char charToMap ) {
        return (int) charToMap - (int) leftBoundary;
    }

    public static void mySort( char[] array ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < array.length-1; j++ ) {
                if ( array[j] > array[j+1] ) {
                    char t = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, but sadly, I am banned from using it. This is exactly how I started my project before being told that I couldn't utilize this method.

Comment: @AraniqueBrown You cant use Maps?

Comment: Nope, no maps allowed. Literally had to start over from scratch because I used them.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the method I was going for.

Comment: @AraniqueBrown You are welcome. If the answer was enough for you, plase consider marking it as the correct answer and/or upvoting it. If you need a more efficient space approach, you will need to change how the data is mapped to the array.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as iterating through your charArray and then using these if/else.
In order to know what a element is you should use the ascii assigning table https://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-java

```
   for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
       int asciiValue = int(charValue);

       if(asciiValue == 11 || (asciiValue >= 28 && asciiValue <= 31) {
           whiteSpace++;
       }
   }
```

Apply the same to textual (65 - 90 and 97 - 122), numeric (48 - 57) and symbol

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. Can I just asked why is the asciiValue == 1 in the code? Shouldn't it just be the second half, if the value is between 28 and 31?

Comment: was a typo of mine - I meant to type 11 -> which is also a whitespace

Comment: if I could helped I would be pleased if you could accept my solution - otherwise feedback or further questions would be nice :D

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: thats awesome :) could u please accept the answer by clicking on the tick?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap to count the freq of the characters, where the character is the key itself and increment the value when you found that value. Your current algorithm is O(n^2) because yo have a for inside another but if you use the hashmap dicrease on O(n)

Ex.

```
    String text = "Hello world";
    HashMap<Character, Integer> chars = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){

        //Get the current char
        char letter = text.charAt(i);

        //If the hashmap has the key is a new ocurrence
        if(chars.containsKey(letter)){
            chars.put(letter, chars.get(letter) + 1);
        }else{
            chars.put(letter, 1);
        }
    }
```

And after that you have to categorize the keys.

```
    for(char tempChar : chars.keySet()){
        //Sort the current char by type
    }
```

You have two iterations with O(n) in time complexity. So it is O(n) at the end and no O(n^2).

Your current algorithm is not good for big amount of data.

Check this to understand why. [Big-O Algorithm Complexity](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

Regards.

Comment: So? Why you would like a solution that is not the best? It is an approach.